# Apache MINA Vysper documentation?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, xmpp, apache-mina, apache-vysper

I plan on making an instant messaging app on Android and iOS, where you can chat to other people with the app, along with some custom features.

I’m going to use the [XMPP protocol](http://xmpp.org/), and make a custom [extension](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/) for it. I plan on making a Java application running on [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/) (AWS) so it's scalable.

After researching [server options](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) I’ve decided to use [Apache Vysper](http://mina.apache.org/vysper/).

However, I’ve never made a proper Java application before, and have never used XMPP, AWS or Vysper – so I’m rather reliant on good documentation :-)

The Apache Vysper project is very new and so [the docs](http://mina.apache.org/vysper/documentation.html) are a bit sparse. I was wondering if I was missing something, should I be using the [general MINA docs](http://mina.apache.org/documentation.html) as well? Are there other resources 
elsewhere I don’t know about?

> “Apache Vysper can run stand-alone or embedded into another
>   application.”

To be honest I’m just as lost when it comes to working out what to use to make a Java application anyway. Do you know if the AWS Java SDK has everything I need to make an application to use on AWS? And then is it a simple matter of integrating Vysper into this? Or do I need to make a Java application using something such as the [Spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/)?

Thanks for taking the time to help me. If you know anything that could clarify the situation I would really appreciate it :-)  --and sorry be being a bit useless, but hey, we've all got to start somewhere right ;)

Comment: Hi @Shaji. I've been trying to create an XMPPConnection but the the connection fails. The XMPPServer starts OK, though. Could you please look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245311/xmppconnection-doesnt-connect) and see if you can help? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, as the founder of Vysper I apologize that the documentation is lacking completeness.

To answer your question(s).

Most Java applications bring their own ready-to-go start scripts with them.
Vysper is no exception. You get the pre-packaged download here:
http://mina.apache.org/vysper-project/downloads.html

Ok, before running it, you need to have Java installed, whether you're on your own machine, AWS, a server or a virtual machine anywhere else. Get it from Oracle, or use the package management of your Linux distribution. Make sure that after installing Java, you can execute "java -version" on the command line and you are all set.

Then, unpack the Vysper download, change to the bin/ directory and execute "run.sh" or "run.bat", depending on your OS.

Please note that support for Vysper - besides here on StackOverflow - is available on the MINA user mailing list here:
http://mina.apache.org/vysper-project/mailing_lists.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just wanted to check more than anything else :-) And thank you for Vysper!

Comment: @zillion1 I hope you can see my question,recently I am studying vysper, so I find a client implemented by stropheJs, but I don't know how to set the spring-config to make the client can connect the server,can you help me! thank you very much!